# Como aplicar o conceito de 3 camadas com o GridView C#?

Tags: asp.net, mvc, gridview

Tenho um projeto onde apresento um `Gridview` em um projeto Webforms Asp.net C#.
Tentei aplicar o conceito de 3 camada desta forma, porem a pagina só da reload e o grid não aparece na pagina.

Segue o exemplo do código abaixo:

```
public class bltboletoDAL
{

    public DataTable GetDataGridView(DataTable Dt, int CodMorador)
    {
        MySqlDataReader Dr;
        MySqlConnection Con = Conexao.GetConnection();
        Conexao.AbrirConexao(Con);


        MySqlCommand Cmd;
        String Sql = "SELECT NumDocumento, Concat(Replace(Replace(Replace(Format(ValorBoleto, 2), '.', '|'), ',', '.'), '|', ',')) As ValorBoleto, DATE_FORMAT( VencimentoBoleto,  '%d/%m/%y' ) AS  'VencimentoBoleto',DATE_FORMAT( DataPagamento,  '%d/%m/%y' ) AS  'DataPagamento' From TbFatura where CodMorador=@v1 and Pago=1 ORDER BY VencimentoBoleto";

        Cmd = new MySqlCommand(Sql, Con);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", CodMorador);

        Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();



        if (Dr.Read())
        {
            Dt.Load(Dr);

        }
        else
        { 

        }

        return Dt;





    }
}
```

***Camada de negocio.***

```
 public class bltboletoBusiness
{
    public void ViewGrid(GridView Grid)
    {
        Grid.Visible = true;
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        var SetTable = new bltboletoDAL();
        Dt = SetTable.GetDataGridView(Dt, ModuloGlobal.Global.CodMorador);

        Grid.DataSource = Dt;
    }
}
```

***Camada de visualização.***

```
protected void btnUltimosPagamentos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var blt = new bltboletoBusiness();
        blt.ViewGrid(GridBltEmAberto);

        GridBltEmAberto.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Para quem estiver com a mesma ou uma dificuldade próxima a essa, foi resolvido com o .DataBind() na camada de Negocio

Comment: cadê o Grid.DataBind()?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que chamar o método DataBind do grid:

```
public void ViewGrid(GridView Grid)
{
    Grid.Visible = true;
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    var SetTable = new bltboletoDAL();
    Dt = SetTable.GetDataGridView(Dt, ModuloGlobal.Global.CodMorador);

    Grid.DataSource = Dt;
    Grid.DataBind();
}
```